# How to delete a record from Airtable and reflect that deletion in Postgres database using Zapier?

Tags: postgresql, zapier, airtable

I was wondering if there was a simple way to trigger a deletion on my postgres database when I delete a record in Airtable. Currently working in zapier but I only see options for triggering on creation of a new record or update of an existing record.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options you can try.

1. Directly  create your own custom Postgres zapier APP using; https://node-postgres.com/ ,
2. Use some middleware services to generate postgres APIs and use zapier webhook APP to make the API calls e.g
   https://supabase.com/ ,https://postgrest.org/en/stable/index.html